# How do I add only new data to an Excel Data model?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, query

I have a sheet with 1000s of rows of historical sales data, and I want to be able to export "sales month to date.csv" from my CRM package, and for those new values which have not been seen before to be added to the bottom of my table.

Everytime I hit refresh on my table though, and add the "sales month to date.csv" it deletes all the data I had before and just leaves me with the latest data!

I'm sure / hope this is an easy fix but I cannot figure it out at all!

TIA

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, this seems to be the default behavior.

When data is taken from the web site, it automatically populates all the data in the current table. The raw data will be overwritten.

As a workaround, I suggest you create a second table, get data in this empty table.

Comment: Many thanks for your response, how would you propose I merge the historical & new data sets?

Comment: Also, if it makes any difference, the data import is done via .csv files, which have been exported from the CRM system, rather than direct import from the website.